# Unable to refer Kotlin data class field in JNI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a JNI code that intends to modify a field value present in a data class.
I'm unable to reference the data class method to do so. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int, val hasPet : Boolean)

//method in the activity
private fun modifyUserName(){
    val user = User("Vikram", 28, false)
    setSampleObject(user)
}

external fun setSampleObject(sampleUser: User)

//Method in JNI.
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_samplemvvm_view_nativekit_NativeCPPActivity_setSampleObject(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                         jobject thiz,
                                                                         jobject sample_user) {

 jclass sampleData = env->GetObjectClass(sample_user);
 jfieldID name = env->GetFieldID(sampleData,"getName","Ljava/lang/String;");
 env -> SetObjectField(sample_user,name,env->NewStringUTF("Test"));
 }
```

The getName method in the double quotation in the JNI method is displayed in red colour and the application crashes with the following error.

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending exception 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/String;" field "getName" in class 
"Lcom/example/samplemvvm/view/nativekit/user/User;"
```

Comment: `getName()` would be the name of a JVM method representing the generated getter function. The field should be named `name` IIRC.

Comment: @CommonsWare That worked. Thank you :) Please post it as an answer. I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```c
jfieldID name = env->GetFieldID(sampleData,"getName","Ljava/lang/String;");
```

However, `getName()` would be the name of the generated JVM method that serves as the getter for that property. The backing field would be named `name`. So, if you really want the field, change `"getName"` to `"name"`.

You might want to consider switching to look up the `getName()` method, though. That way, if you override the getter in your Kotlin class, your JNI uses the overridden function.